# bonobo, can't access repo on localhost

Tags: git, windows-7, iis-7, bonobo

Running on Windows 7 I've installed IIS7 and followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/jakubgarfield/Bonobo-Git-Server). I've managed to setup the bonobo git server and use it. I made an empty test repo, and when I tried cloning the repo using git shell using the command

> git clone hxxp://myhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/test-repo.git

(when: hxxp == http)

it put out

> git clone hxxp://myhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/test-repo.git
>   Cloning into 'test-repo'...
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>   Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

(when myhost is localhost) Am I missing something? I've tried to play with the Win7 and IIS7 access rights and it didn't work

Comment: In the end I just decided to deviate from the installation instructions, instead of loading the folder in IIS7 and turning it into an application I've instead turned it into a web site. I've disabled all manner of authentication and currently even anonymous users can,in fact, fetch the repos and push. 
I guess the problem was security, what was it exactly I don't know. but at least the repos are useable now between workstations. but as the repos grow, I would very much like them being more secured!

Answer (score 0):

Bonobo serves git repositories hosted with it via http protocol.

I believe the following should work (`http` instead of `hxxp`).

```
git clone http://myhost/Bonobo.Git.Server/test-repo.git
```

If it doesn't work try:

```
git clone http://myhost/test-repo.git
```

Comment: i've added hxxp instead of http so that stackoverflow won't highlight it as a link. the problem is the either win7 or iis7 is blocking git requests going through bonobo running on localhost